# CSS to properly align header image?

Tags: css, alignment, css-position, vertical-alignment

I need to align the lifestyle furniture ad image in the header for http://test.wizs.com/. I need it to be flush against the right side. See how it is vertically aligned to the top? I want it to be in line with the logo.

Everything that I have tried is not working. Some of the css that I have tried makes the image go halfway off the page... :/

Currently, the CSS is:

```
#header .widget {
    left: 50%;  
    padding-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible markup which displays the issue.

Comment: @Scott - Can you please explain what you mean? Please excuse my ignorance..  I tried to look up what you were referring to so I could answer, but am still unclear what you are asking...

Comment: You've provided 1 simple CSS rule.. Please provide all relevant HTML and CSS to your problem. Don't ask users to scour your site for specific code.. post the code here.

Comment: @Scott - If I had the other code I would have. I'm sorry. From where i am working and what I know at this point, I was only dealing with wordpress, and my theme. I'm trying to learn. I actually really want to learn how to be better at this. Can you point me to a good reference to try to learn from so that i can provide specific code in the future? I'm being sincere.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what you mean.

I added:

```
.proadszone-4788 img {
   padding-top: 27px;
}
```

Comment: I added the code you sent above but it did not doing anything. I was able to set the ad to be centered in the ad plugin and that took care of the vertical alignment.... so I am trying to get the ad to be right aligned with similar right padding to that of how the logo is left aligned but has left padding

Comment: still didnt do anything

Comment: Are you updating the live site?

Comment: I resolved it.. I think. I changed the left value in my original code to 55% and it aligned right.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: i was wrong. I have it resolved for some screens, but not for reasonable scree sizes ... I think the container for the logo must be limiting how much room the header ad has to expand?  [link] (http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//test.wizs.com&w=1024&h=601&a=1&s=1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
.wppas_custom_widgets-36 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

and remove this css

```
#header .widget {
}
```

[image]

Try this it may help

Comment: That did not work. It made the header ad move to where it looked like it was on its own row above the logo

Comment: Oh ! Let me check and get back to you !